# Iterating two big data frames in R. Comparing  2 different positions at the same time using conditions

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply

I tried to solve this problem in PERL, but it only works with lesser data, so I need a solution in R, which I guess is faster and easier then PERL, anyway. I got one file like this one with two positions in the genome ( first and second column) and the distance bteween them (third column)

```
cg00000029  cg01016459  848
cg00000029  cg02021817  38
cg00000029  cg02851944  13
cg00000029  cg02976952  238
cg00000029  cg03943270  93
cg00000029  cg07396495  604
cg00000029  cg12190057  929
```

And my second file is this one, with the position in the genome and one expression value in each column, for each sample ( 1 to 6)

```
TargetID    sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample6
cg00000029  0.157   0.444   0.466   0.805   0.5489  0.448
cg01016459  0.873   0.930   0.926   0.942   0.932   0.9128  
cg03943270  0.871   0.920   0.926   0.942   0.942   0.942
```

In fact I have 100 samples. My idea is to get a final file for each sample with the expression values
instead the cg's and the distance. For example, for sample 1

```
0.157  0.873 848
0.157  0.871  93
```

for sample 2

```
0.444   0.930 848
0.444   0.920   93
```

In PERL I have no problems when I got only two samples, I load the files in two estructures, hashes of arrays, and then I compare them using nested foreach loops, but it take so much time only for 2 samples, imagine 100! I tried in R, loading the data in 2 data frames and use something as

```
expression[rownames(expression) %in% rownames(distances),]
```

the problem is that I need something like a loop or apply function to iterate over the expression data using the first cpg value and then the second , if they are in pairs in expression, put the expression values and the distances.

Any ideas would be welcome

Thanks in advance

`

Comment: Does the first column in the first file actually vary?  And, if so, does it go through every permutation with the second column?  I can see that "cg00000029  cg01016459" appears for column 1 and 2, but does the reverse appear?

Comment: No, in fact there is only one distance for 2 points, it don't repeat

Comment: The first column vary, but in fact there is only one distance for 2 points, it don't repeat, so once the distances for this particulary cpg are calculated, they don't repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your first data is in `dat`

```
structure(list(V1 = c("cg00000029", "cg00000029", "cg00000029", 
"cg00000029", "cg00000029", "cg00000029", "cg00000029"), V2 = c("cg01016459", 
"cg02021817", "cg02851944", "cg02976952", "cg03943270", "cg07396495", 
"cg12190057"), V3 = c(848L, 38L, 13L, 238L, 93L, 604L, 929L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

and second set is in `target`

```
structure(list(TargetID = c("cg00000029", "cg01016459", "cg03943270"
), sample1 = c(0.157, 0.873, 0.871), sample2 = c(0.444, 0.93, 
0.92), sample3 = c(0.466, 0.926, 0.926), sample4 = c(0.805, 0.942, 
0.942), sample5 = c(0.5489, 0.932, 0.942), sample6 = c(0.448, 
0.9128, 0.942)), .Names = c("TargetID", "sample1", "sample2", 
"sample3", "sample4", "sample5", "sample6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

`match()` will get you what you're looking for.  I would use reshape and plyr packages.  Specifically `melt` and `ddply` but I'm sure there is a apply version too.

```
target.melt <- melt(target,id.var='TargetID')

my.func <- function(lookup,df) {
  cg.one <- lookup$value[match(df$V1,lookup$TargetID)]
  cg.two <- lookup$value[match(df$V2,lookup$TargetID)]

  return(list(cgone=cg.one,cgtwo=cg.two,distance=df$V3))
}

out <- dlply(target.melt,.(variable),my.func,df=dat)
```

there are a bunch of NAs with your data since the second data set is incomplete but what you asked for is there:

```
> na.omit(as.data.frame(out[[1]]))
  cgone cgtwo distance
1 0.157 0.873      848
5 0.157 0.871       93
>
```

Comment: Thanks Justin! How does it work melt and dlply? It is the first time that I see both

Comment: That is a long answer!  melt, in this case, is used to take your second data set and put it in a "long" format which is easier for plyr to work with.  the plyr functions all end in ply and the leading two letters tell you what goes in and what goes out (in this case a dataframe in and a list out).  the second argument is a splitting variable.  in this case, split target.melt into separate dataframes based on unique values found in teh calue column... clear as mud I'm sure!

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two data.frames with `merge`, convert the result to the tall format with `melt`, and then apply a function (e.g., to save to a file) on each piece of the result with `d_pply`.

```
# Sample data
n <- length(LETTERS)
d1 <- cbind( expand.grid( LETTERS, LETTERS ), rnorm( n*n ) )
names(d1) <- c("id1", "id2", "distance")
d1 <- d1[ as.character(d1$id1) < as.character(d1$id2), ]
d2 <- as.data.frame( matrix( rnorm(n*6), nr=n ) )
d2 <- data.frame( id=LETTERS, d2 )
names( d2 )[-1] <- paste( "sample", 1:6, sep="")

# If the distance data.frame only contains half the pairs,
# i.e., if it only contains one of (a,b) and (b,a), 
# add the missing ones.    
d1a <- d1
d1b <- d1[,c(2,1,3)]
names(d1b) <- names(d1a)
d1 <- rbind( d1a, d1b )
d1 <- d1[ ! duplicated( d1[,1:2]), ]

# Merge the two data.frames    
d <- merge( d1, d2, by.x="id1", by.y="id" )

# Convert to tall format
library(reshape2)
d <- melt(d, id.vars=c("id1", "id2", "distance"))

# Apply a function to each chunk
d_ply( d, "variable", function (u) { 
  cat( "Would save ", nrow(u), " rows to ", as.character(u$variable[1]), "\n" ) 
} )
```